# Is there a way to get direct_to_template to pass RequestContext in django?

Tags: django, django-views, requestcontext

I have found myself writing the same view over and over.  It is basically this:

```
def home_index(request):
    return render_to_response('home/index.html', RequestContext(request))
```

To keep with the dry principal, I would like to utilize a [generic view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#generic-views). I have seen [direct_to_template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template), but it passes an empty context.  So how can I use a generic view and still get the power of RequestContext?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`direct_to_template`, like all generic views, already uses a RequestContext, so you don't need to do anything else to enable it.

However I'm not sure if what you're really asking is whether you can pass additional context items - and you can, by using the `extra_context` dictionary parameter, either in the URLconf or in a wrapper view.

Also you should ask yourself why you're creating multiple views that simply render templates. If that's what you are mostly doing, you may find that Django's built-in [flatpages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/flatpages/) app is better than hard-coding your views.

Comment: Turns out I had a syntax error, so thanks for clarifying that `RequestContext` should be there since that made me look at the template again.  And your right, it looks like I should use flatpages.  Appreciate the info and help.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having the same problem, and writing something like this, but looking at the [direct_to_template code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/simple.py#L4) it seems in new versions of django this problem doesn't exist anymore. direct_to_template passes the correct context.